# How to get array of only numbers from string array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have this array od strings and numbers: array=["er2", "56t", "5"];
and i need to get this array with only numbers: array[2,56,5];

Help somebody please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we need to do is iterate over the array and remove the characters, a simple way of doing this is by replacing the characters regex

```js
array = ["er2", "56t", "5"];

cleanArray = array.map( function(value) {
    return value.replace(/\D+/g, '');
})

console.log(cleanArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the letters with regex pattern and then use `map`

```js
 array=["er2", "56t", "5"]
res=array.map(o=>parseInt(o.replace(/[a-zA-Z]+/,"")))
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can .match method of string to get the numbers out of string

```js
var array=["er2", "56t", "5"];

var result  = array.map(obj  => {

var matches = obj.match(/(\d+)/);     
     if (matches) { 
        return matches[0];       
     } 
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this example

```js
const array=["er2", "56t", "5"]
const output = array.map(entry => +entry.match(/\d+/)[0])

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = ["er2", "56t", "5"];
arr.map((val)=> val.match(/(\d+)/g)).flat();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want:

```js
const array = ["er2", "56t", "5"];
const res = array.map(x => +x.replace(/[^0-9]*/g, ''))
console.log(res);// [2,56,5]
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: Please clarify the question if it needs to be limited to just integers or decimals as well.

```js
const convertToNumber = (numberString) => {

    //seperate number from string & filter out empty entries
    let stringList = numberString.split(/([0-9]+)/).filter(Boolean);
  //convert number from string & filter out failed conversions
  let numberList = stringList.map(entry => Number.isNaN(+entry) ? null : +entry).filter(Boolean);
  
  //if conversion result into more then one number return undefined else return number
  if(numberList.length !== 1) return;
    else return numberList[0];
}

const array = ["er2", "56t", "5"];
const newArray = array.map(entry => convertToNumber(entry))
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Sorry, only integer. Thank you!